# Ansible variable in jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a small playbook with jinja2 template to apply nginx configuration.
This template uses some variables.

In my variables file I have:

```
---
domains:
  - test@example.com
```

In my template file I have:

```
server_name  {{ domains }};
```

Once playbook deployed, in my config file I have:

```
server_name  ['test@example.com'];
```

What can I do to print only test@example.com? without ['...']?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one domain, you can just create a [simple variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#simple-variables) instead of a [list variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#list-variables):

```yaml
domain: test@example.com
```

and than use a Jinja2 template such as:

```
server_name  {{ domain }};
```

If you have more than one:

```yaml
domains:
  - one@example.com
  - two@example.com
  - three@example.com
```

you can [loop](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for) over the list:

```
{% for domain in domains %}
server_name  {{ domain }};
{% endfor %}
```

This will create a file like:

```
server_name  one@example.com;
server_name  two@example.com;
server_name  three@example.com;
```